# ERROR: remote query result rowtype does not match the specified FROM clause rowtype, on remote function call

Tags: postgresql, function

When calling a function that returns two OUT variables as a record type, the above error is thrown.

I have created this remote function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_del(rpt_map 
json, OUT del_qry text, OUT start_date date)
 RETURNS record
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare rpts json;rpt_list text[]; 
begin

select to_char(now()::date - interval '3 Years', 'YYYY-01-01')::date 
into start_date;

rpt_list = (ARRAY(SELECT json_object_keys(rpt_map)));

del_qry = (select string_agg('delete from rpt.' || rpt || 
                  ' where dt < ''' || start_date || '', E';\n')
           from unnest(rpt_list) as rpt)::text;

end;
$function$
```

I attempt to call it like this:

```
SELECT t.del_qry, t.start_date
FROM dblink('my_conn', 'select public.get_del(''' || rpt_map || ''')') 
AS t(del_qry text, start_date date);
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: remote query result rowtype does not match the 
specified FROM clause rowtype
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I get exactly the same error.

> ERROR: remote query result rowtype does not match the specified FROM
> clause rowtype

I have a VIEW using dblink and initially I create a VIEW using "SELECT *" and it works fine, but after a while my queries started to fail.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_table
 AS
 SELECT remote_data.field1, remote_data.field2, remote_data.field3
FROM dblink('hostaddr=<IP> port=<port> dbname=<my_db> user=<user> password=<pass>'::text,
'SELECT * FROM public.one_table'::text) AS remote_data(field1 bigint, field2 text, field3 date);
```

During the investigation, I realized that the error is related to the order of the fields in the SELECT statement.

So I changed the "SELECT *" to "SELECT field1, field2, field3 ..." and my queries using this VIEW are ok.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.my_table
 AS
 SELECT remote_data.field1, remote_data.field2, remote_data.field3
FROM dblink('hostaddr=<IP> port=<port> dbname=<my_db> user=<user> password=<pass>'::text,
'SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM public.one_table'::text) AS remote_data(field1 bigint, field2 text, field3 date);
```